# Get the current typed value in Chosen

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-chosen

Edit--------------
As you type in a Chosen object, it filters out to the possible values. When I type in "r" Chosen shows that the only possible option is "red" and I can select that.

If I ever access $("#myselectid").val() and I haven't selected a possible selection, it will be null. I need to capture the single "r" that the user typed in so that I can the "r" do the ajax script to retrieve the additional r values such as red1, red2, red3

Original------------
I have an html select object with some options. I successfully display it as a "Chosen" option.

I want to append the list based off a query as they are typing. I have the ajax response working.

The problem is I need access to the current typed value in the Chosen object.

For example, assume that the selections are red, green, blue, purple. As I type the first "r" Chosen automatically filters it to just "red", but I want to send an ajax request to retrieve more "r" values like red1, red2, red3, red4 etc...

How do I read the "r" so I can send that to my javascript function that creates the ajax request?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code, what you've tried, etc :)

Comment: I don't even know where to begin! The html <select> could have something like <select onchange="callmyajaxfunction()> but I don't know if select objects work like <input type="text"/> objects

Comment: Another option might be something like $("#myselectid").trigger()... but I have little understanding of the trigger function of the Chosen

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly your needs. You need to use both fixed and dynamic sources?

Comment: But have you tried to use the `source` option?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with the source option... what does that mean exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91123/discussion-between-matthew-and-buzinas).

Comment: Select2 library that you were mentioning in your chat was useful for me. Thank you Buzinas.